# Find center of circle defined by 2 points and their tangent intersection

Tags: javascript, math, vector-graphics

[image: example]

I have Cartesian coordinates P, P0 and P1, how do I find C?

Note that C is also the orthocenter of the triangle which has P as a vertex and P0 and P1 as altitudes.

This code will run a couple hundred times per second in a graphics renderer, in a program that is already doing complex physics, so it needs to be fast. I'm doing using it to calculate control points for quadratic curves. If possible, I'd like to avoid trig functions and calculating angles and stick to pure vector math.

Pure math answers are fine, even though I'm programming this in Javascript. Just keep in mind that the simpler the answer, the better, since any vector operation costs time.

Comment: I'm not asking for code, I'm asking for a solution to this math problem. The question indicates that math answers are fine, I just tagged this as Javascript, because that's what I'm using. I also tagged it as Vector Graphics, as that's the domain of the question.

Comment: Please consider asking this question at math.stackexchange.com. This site right here is not meant to explain algebra but to answer questions about programming.

Comment: You might be correct about that, my apologies. Problem is, take MBo's answer (which I'm currently checking). The first method is certainly correct, but trying to solve for the solution turns out to be incredibly expensive processor-wise. I'm currently checking the second method, which is turning out to be very efficient. On first glance, the first one seemed more promising and elegant. So yeah, it's sort of in-between the two sites. Again, my apologies for asking it here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because, as OP states in comments, it seeks a solution to a maths problem.

Comment: The question has an accepted answer and seeks a programming solution to a maths problem. I don't see the issue? If I would've posted this in the math exchange, I would not have gotten a useful answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method 1:
Vectors CP0 and PP0 are perpendicular, and CP1 and PP1 are perpendicular, so we can write system of two equations for dot products of these vector pairs and find two unknown CX and CY (center coordinates)

```
CP0 = (CX - P0.X, CY - P0.Y)
CP1 = (CX - P1.X, CY - P1.Y)
PP0 = (P.X - P0.X, P.Y - P0.Y)
PP1 = (P.X - P1.X, P.Y - P1.Y)

Dot(CP0, PP0 ) = 0
Dot(CP1, PP1 ) = 0

(CX - P0.X) * (P.X - P0.X) + (CY - P0.Y) * (P.Y - P0.Y) = 0
(CX - P1.X) * (P.X - P1.X) + (CY - P1.Y) * (P.Y - P1.Y) = 0
```

Method 2:
Middle point M between P0 and P1 has coordinates

```
  M.X = (P0.X + P1.X) / 2          ///1
  M.Y = (P0.Y + P1.X) / 2          ///2
  Distance P-M is DM
  DM_Squared = (P.X-M.X)^2 + (P.Y-M.Y)^2     ///3
  L, D distances are from your notation
  L_Squared = (P.X-P0.X)^2 + (P.Y-P0.Y)^2     ///4
```

Theta is angle P0PC

```
 Cos(Theta) = Length(P - M) / Length(P - P0) = DM / L 
 D = Length(C - P) = L / Cos(Theta) = L * L / DM
 and finally
 C = P - L^2 * (P0 - M) / DM^2

 Coeff = L_Squared / DM_Squared           ///5
 C.X = P.X - Coeff * (P.X - M.X)         ///6
 C.Y = P.Y - Coeff * (P.Y - M.Y)         ///7
```

Formulas 1..7 are ready-to-use

Comment: Thanks for expanding the answer, I was already checking it for correctness. I'll accept it in a minute once I've verified it :)